# Preposition to use with "cruise"

Tags: prepositions

Can I use "at" as a preposition with "cruise", like in this example:

> a tourist vessel cruising at the Caribbean Sea

Maybe "in" is better and more natural here, but I'm just asking if "at" would be considered an error in this sentence.

Comment: In this context, _at_ suggests to me _in the direction of_ rather than _upon_ which is probably intended.

Comment: In fact, you don't need a preposition there. "a tourist vessel cruising the Caribbean Sea."

Comment: And no, you can't use *at* in this context.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have always seen the use of *on*, and have also used it myself. I honestly can't think of a scenario in which *at* would have a valid use with the *cruise*. I'm fairly confident that saying *I was at the cruise* or *the cruise at the Caribbean* would be flat out incorrect, not just less popular usage.

Edit: However, I believe it is technically correct to state something like *a cruise in the Caribbean Sea*, but that it's just less common.

Comment: See also my comment at OP.

Comment: That's what I figured.

Comment: Please look at the Help Center to view the requirements for a good answer on ELU. Answers lacking linked and attributed supporting references (example sentences given in dictionaries, quotes from respected authors / publications) come across as (and sometimes are) mere opinion, which can have as much chance of being incorrect as correct. [Unless supporting evidence is found for your claim, I'll have to downvote; I feel 'cruising on the Mediterranean' say is **less** idiomatic than 'cruising in the Mediterranean'.]

Comment: And [these Google 4-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cruising+in+the+Caribbean%2Ccruising+on+the+Caribbean%2Ccruising+in+the+Mediterranean%2Ccruising+on+the+Mediterranean&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccruising%20in%20the%20Caribbean%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccruising%20in%20the%20Mediterranean%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccruising%20on%20the%20Mediterranean%3B%2Cc0) are fairly convincing evidence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough, I will try to provide more support in my future answers.

Comment: I've now downvoted. Fair enough?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cruising+the+sea%2C+cruising+in+the+sea%2C+cruising+on+the+sea%2C+cruising+at+the+sea&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccruising%20the%20sea%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccruising%20on%20the%20sea%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Kris But this answer doesn't address the cruise + DO choice, so how is that relevant here?

Answer (score -1):

If 'cruise' is used as a noun, it would be 'on'. For eg.

> Alice is on a cruise until the end of the week

If 'cruise' is used as a verb, there are several usages depending on the context. A few examples that may help:

> Do not cruise 'with' the engine turned off
>       The vessel is cruising 'on' the Caribbean sea 
>       The luxury boat is cruising 'off/along' the coast

Comment: Thank you, but sometimes there are several options and some are just more popular. I'm just asking if "cruise at the Caribbean Sea" is a plain error or correct, but less popular usage.

Comment: I think "cruise at the Caribben" may be an incorrect usage.

Comment: We say that a ship is _at sea_ when it has left its port, but we never use _at_ with the name of a particular sea.